# mcrypt_generic vs mcrypt_encrypt

Tags: php, mcrypt

Does anyone know the difference between mcrypt_generic and mcrypt_encrypt when it comes to encryption in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mcrypt_encrypt()` combines the functionality of several methods, whereas `mcrypt_generic()` must be called within a certain sequence of other `mcrypt_*` calls.  You would use `mcrypt_generic()` if you needed the flexibility of the lower-level API, whereas `mcrypt_encrypt()` acts as a higher-level utility.

This example in the PHP documentation shows a good comparison between the two API approaches. It refers to `mcrypt_ecb()`, but for the purposes of this comparison you can consider it to be similar to `mcrypt_encrypt()`.

From http://us.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php

```
$key = "this is a secret key";
$input = "Let us meet at 9 o'clock at the secret place.";

$encrypted_data = mcrypt_ecb (MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $input, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
```

Or:

```
$key = "this is a secret key";
$input = "Let us meet at 9 o'clock at the secret place.";

$td = mcrypt_module_open('tripledes', '', 'ecb', '');
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$encrypted_data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_module_close($td);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-generic.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

These functions has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0. Relying on these function is highly discouraged.

Nowadays, the best option apparently is:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: So what we should use now? Adding that information would make your question way more helpful.